# Sum Hash Values Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes

```
players =  [{:id=>1, :name=>"Alda", :dice_count=>5, :hand=>[6, 5, 2, 4, 3]},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"Gonzalo", :dice_count=>5, :hand=>[1, 5, 1, 1]},
 {:id=>3, :name=>"Markus", :dice_count=>5, :hand=>[6, 2, 5, 1]},
 {:id=>4, :name=>"Luella", :dice_count=>5, :hand=>[4, 5, 1, 6, 5]}]
```

and I would like to sum the size of each `:hand` value in the array.  Is there a simple way to do this?

So the output would be the sum of each `:hand.size`.  In the above case the output would be `18`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
players.map { |player| player[:hand].size }.reduce(:+) # => 18
```

Answer (score 3):

A single pass solution:

```
players.inject(0) { | a, e | a + e[:hand].size } 
# => 18
```

Note `inject` is just another name for `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

This one is just for fun, assumes `hand` is always the last element in the hash.

```
p players.map(&:flatten).map(&:last).map(&:size).reduce(:+)
```